# Countif 3d usage in Excel

Tags: excel, countif

I am trying to use countifs function. I have to do this:

> countifs('Sheet 2'!$E$7:$U$88, "Completed", 'Sheet 2'!$E$4:$U$4, L4, 'Sheet 2'!$V$7:$V$88, M4)

But the function returns me #Value.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say definitively that this will eliminate the error you're seeing, but note that neither your `criteria_range2` nor your `criteria_range3` has the same dimension as your `criteria_range1`, which is necessary per [the documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countifs-function-HA102753238.aspx):

> **IMPORTANT** Each additional range must have the same number of rows and columns as the criteria_range1 argument. The ranges do not have to
>   be adjacent to each other.

Note that this might not be "the whole solution", since (as of this answer's first posting) it isn't clear that there aren't other potential problems with the data in the ranges provided or with the criteria corresponding to those ranges.